# Getting errror - NullInjectorError: No provider for NgRedux! when integrating redux implementation

Tags: angular, redux, ngredux

I was modifying the existing project to implement the redux implementation. Made the code changes, and found the below error while compiling. According to the learning material I have referred, ngRedux need not be added into the providers. Upon adding it to the providers, still getting error.

```
 **AppModule.ts**
    //Activation of store.
    import {NgRedux , NgReduxModule} from '@angular-redux/store';
    import {IAppState,INITIAL_STATE,rootReducer} from '../store';
    //Other Imports here 
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ViewallComponent,
        WorkoutComponent,
        CategoryComponent,
        TrackComponent,
        TestComponent,
        CategoryPipe,
        ActiveworkoutComponent,
        WorkoutPipe,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        FusionChartsModule.forRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FintTheme)
      ],
      providers: [
        WorkoutService,
        CategoryService,
        ActiveworkoutService
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]

    })

    export class AppModule { 
      constructor (ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
           ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
        }

    }
```

Had made appropriate changes in component , and made the store files.

Error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppModule -> NgRedux]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppModule -> NgRedux]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgRedux!
Stack trace:
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NullInjector.prototype.get@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33896:19
resolveToken@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34133:17
tryResolveToken@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34077:16
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/StaticInjector.prototype.get@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33974:20
resolveToken@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34133:17
tryResolveToken@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34077:16`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **`NgReduxModule`** under imports of module.ts

```
imports: [
    NgReduxModule
]
```

Comment: I got below error on using NgReduxModule.forRoot() import.
Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgReduxModule'. ("forRoot" has been remove in 5.0 beta.0)
Imported NgReduxModule and it worked.Thanks!